# Does Chrome,Firefox,etc specify max-device-width to mobile?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I add a media query to my html file

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="xxx-mobile.css" media="screen and (max-device-width:360px)">
```

then I adjust the width to find the point the css will have effect.

The browsers I tested in my mobile are:

1. chrome;
2. firefox;
3. opera;
4. android webkit browser;

Results are as follows:

1. chrome, firefox and opera change style at the point max-device-width:360px;
2. android webkit browser change style at the point max-device-width:1080px(my screen resolution is 1080*1920);

I want to know chrome whether specify mobile max-device-width or not and standard of the max-device-width sepecified.

Comment: Did you include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`?

Comment: @Manngo I didn't add it before, but after I add it, though have a good look, just as font looks bigger, but the point of css effect doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better view port size , their standard and uses take a look at bellow links

["sizes for various devices"](http://viewportsizes.com/)

for other trends [look here](https://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp)

and yes do remember to include

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It means max-device-width is not equal to screen resolution, because I find in the link you mentioned iPhone 6 has a viewport size 375*667, while its screen resolution is 750*1334. Then screen width is 2 times of viewport width(while my device is 3 times). I look around the list in that link, I suppose chrome make viewport 300~400(relevant to screen width) to achieve  most sites request of identifying mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I thought either chrome or android webkit browser make something wrong, but now I think they both are right. They all do well, the difference they presented is because device-width is deprecated(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width ).So device-width is the device actual width, and because it is deprecated,it will be treated as width(viewport width) which is not actual device width.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox  provide it you can use

```
max-width: -moz-available;
```